# Wanting to Scrape all "li" elements. Python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, list, beautifulsoup

I am just a real novice when it comes to python but I am really enjoying the learning process. I am interested in data analysis and all I am trying to do is scrape list elements of a wikipedia page.

I have managed to pull the list and prettify it via:

```
music_box = soup.find(class_="div-col")
music_rows = music_box.find_all("li")
for row in music_rows:
    print(row.prettify())
```

Which then provides me with:

```
    <li>
 Natalie Beridze – When Dreams Become Responsibility
</li>

<li>
 <a href="/wiki/The_Specials" title="The Specials">
  The Specials
 </a>
 – Do Nothing
</li>

<li>
 <a href="/wiki/Nine_Inch_Nails" title="Nine Inch Nails">
  Nine Inch Nails
 </a>
 – Your Touch
</li>

<li>
 <a href="/wiki/Phosphorescent_(band)" title="Phosphorescent (band)">
  Phosphorescent
 </a>
 – Song for Zula
```

And essentially I would like to create a function that pulls just the artist and the song. Ideally popping into a list or dictionary.

I think I was getting mixed up though because I was thinking this would work

```
music_info = {}
for index, row in enumerate(music_rows):
    if index == 0:
        music_info['artist'] = row.find("li").get_text("", strip=True)
    (music_info)
```

I am really new to python and have been trying self teach myself and perhaps i haven't quite grasped the fundamentals just yet and If this is something you guys believe i should have known prior to asking you guys just say, this community has been so good to me from joining this year so any advice whether constructive or not is appreciated, thanks guys! Hope y'all are having a happy friday

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: oh of course sorry about that 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Can%27t_Get_You_Out_of_My_Head_(TV_series)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `row.find("li")` to select `<li>` again, as you have selected them in `music_rows = music_box.find_all("li")`. `row.find("li")` will find `<li>` in `row`'s children, not itself. You can try this one:

```
for index, row in enumerate(music_rows):
    music_info = {}
    music_info["artist"], music_info["name"] = map(str.strip, row.get_text("", strip=True).split("–"))
    print(music_info)
```

Comment: Aw you rock! Thanks so much for that, clearly being too keen with row.find, at least I had some aspects of it right haha. Really appreciate the help, hope you have a great rest of your day!